# How to Prevent Websocket Hack when sending from Server to Client in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Hello i'm currently building a messaging system with Websockets(Engine.IO). And i'm afraid I may be exposing myself to a client side hack. What I am doing is filtering the incoming message/data on client side, as "private" or "public", my code is the following:

How can I prevent user from getting "private" data, if he should only get "public"?

```
       var socket = new eio.Socket();       

   socket.onopen = function(){
     console.log("Opened the connection");
   };
   socket.onclose = function(){
   console.log("Connection closed");
   };
   socket.onmessage = function(mess){
    var Message = JSON.parse(mess);
     console.log("a message " + mess );

    if(Message.Type == "Public"){
    console.log("Message is Public" + Message.Message);
    }       

    else if(Message.Type == "Private"){
    console.log("Message is Private " + Message.Message);
    }       

   };
```

Comment: Just don't send private data in the first place then.

Comment: Because it's for a single page app, so I was not sure where to put the code. Since engine.io has only one socket.onsend channel.

Answer (score 1):

Any data you send to a user's browser, can be read by the user one way or the other.

You can send encrypted data to the browser, if it does not need to be read or modified by the client and can be sent as is. Just watch out for reply attacks.